# Can you use shape water to fly?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips

Can I use the 5th edition Druid cantrip *[shape water](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shape-water)* to fly by using the following:

1. Take a 5 ft cube of water say from a lake or well and cast the cantrip once to freeze it.
2. Stand on top of your cube of frozen water (lasts an hour)
3. Cast it again on the cube and this time use it to move the cube 5 feet up in the air.
4. Repeat as needed to move it wherever you want and ride on top of your newly made flying block of ice.

Spell says up to 2 effects active on your water at a time so would this work?

Answer (score 13):

### No

The spell states that:

> You choose an area of water [..] You manipulate
>   it in one of the following ways:
>
> You **instantaneously** move or otherwise change the flow of the water as
>   you direct (EE 21, emphasis mine)

The movement effect does not have a lasting duration, it is instantaneous. That means the spell cannot *hold* the target in place and it will fall right back unless supported in another way. So this will not work with ice or water (combining with *water walk*).

Also, the spell works on "water" and not "things made of water". Whether a block of ice counts as water is questionable and it would be reasonable for a DM to rule that the spell cannot target ice at all.